# Trying to use Iframe to put my c# application on a wordpress website

Tags: c#, iframe

I am finally getting serious about programming and I have created a few c# applications I would like to put on a website, but I am struggling with the concept of Iframes and how to use them to "embed" my applications onto a wordpress website. Is there someone out there who can explain in laymans terms how to use an Iframe so I can put my applications on the web to use for my purposes?

I am not entirely seasoned with programming but I have a good head on my shoulders, I'm just struggling at the moment with this new concept

Comment: You can't. IFrames are used to embed web pages into a website using a URL. Web browsers do not natively support compiled C# applications. If you really want to do this though, you can compile your application for WebAssembly (WASM) and embed it into a website. [Here](https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap) may be a good starting point to do that. However, doing it this way will likely be much slower and use a lot more resources than if you were to just re-write your program using HTML and JavaScript (because WASM is essentially emulating a physical CPU in your browser).

Comment: So if I want to build out a UI for my c# application and integrate that onto a website, I basically won't be able to do that? That is what I am wondering here, at the moment I am more seasoned with c# than I am with html (I have some know how on how it works) and I have very little Java experience.

Comment: [JavaScript is not Java](http://javascriptisnotjava.com/). The only markup language that browsers understand is HTML. You could use ASP.NET which is a backend web framework in C#, but that's all it is. The UI is still in HTML/CSS/JavaScript. The only semi-close framework I can think of is ASP.NET WebForms, but you will still likely need to re-create the entire UI using the tools this framework provides. The only way you would be able to directly embed your application into a website would be using WASM like I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: Yes, my bad, I did not mean that, I have very little JavaScript experience, and thank you for the help, I will have to do my research into WASM and see if that is something I can do, if not, I will have to practice more with HTML and JavaScript if I want to build applications onto a website